# JQuery-Filter form to display only corresponding inputs

Tags: jquery, forms, input

Let's say I have two database tables: Panels and Collection.

I'm trying to add/edit rows in each table using forms. They both have similar fields such as name and price, but they also have fields that are unique.

Using JQuery, how can I consolidate the inputs in one form and only show the inputs that correspond to the table chosen where the row is to be added or edited?

```
<input name="name"></input>
<input name="price"></input
<input name="per_door_price"></input> <!--corresponds only to panel table-->
<input name="series"></input> <!--corresponds only to collection table-->
```

The table would be chosen in another page and sent to the form using $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `this` context or `find` method

```
$('#tables').find('input')
```

**or**

```
$('input', '#tables')
```

This will only target the input elements inside the table with `id="tables"`

Comment: $('#collection').find('#series').toggle();  //many ways to do this.

Comment: I meant to say database tables.